# How to create a one-to-many relationship with JDBI SQL object API?

Tags: java, join, one-to-many, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm creating a simple REST application with dropwizard using JDBI. The next step is to integrate a new resource that has a one-to-many relationship with another one. Until now I couldn't figure out how to create a method in my DAO that retrieves a single object that holds a list of objects from another table.

The POJO representations would be something like this:

User POJO:

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Account POJO:

```
public class Account {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<User> users;

    public Account(int id, String name, List<User> users) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

The DAO should look something like this

```
public interface AccountDAO {

    @Mapper(AccountMapper.class)
    @SqlQuery("SELECT Account.id, Account.name, User.name as u_name FROM Account LEFT JOIN User ON User.accountId = Account.id WHERE Account.id = :id")
    public Account getAccountById(@Bind("id") int id);

}
```

But when the method has a single object as return value (*Account* instead of *List<Account>*) there seems to be no way to access more than one line of the resultSet in the Mapper class. The only solution that comes close I could find is described at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jdbi/4e4EP-gVwEQ/02CRStgYGtgJ but that one also only returns a Set with a single object which does not seem very elegant. (And can't be properly used by the resouce classes.)

There seems to be a way using a *Folder2* in the fluent API. But I don't know how to integrate that properly with dropwizard and I'd rather stick to JDBI's SQL object API as recommended in the dropwizard documentation.

Is there really no way to get a one-to-many mapping using the SQL object API in JDBI? That is such a basic use case for a database that I think I must be missing something.

All help is greatly appreciated,

  Tilman

Answer (score 35, accepted):

OK, after a lot of searching, I see two ways dealing with this:

The **first option** is to retrieve an object for each column and merge it in the Java code at the resource (i.e. do the join in the code instead of having it done by the database).
This would result in something like

```
@GET
@Path("/{accountId}")
public Response getAccount(@PathParam("accountId") Integer accountId) {
    Account account = accountDao.getAccount(accountId);
    account.setUsers(userDao.getUsersForAccount(accountId));
    return Response.ok(account).build();
}
```

This is feasible for smaller join operations but seems not very elegant to me, as this is something the database is supposed to do. However, I decided to take this path as my application is rather small and I did not want to write a lot of mapper code.

The **second option** is to write a mapper, that retrieves the result of the join query and maps it to the object like this:

```
public class AccountMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Account> {

    private Account account;

    // this mapping method will get called for every row in the result set
    public Account map(int index, ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {

        // for the first row of the result set, we create the wrapper object
        if (index == 0) {
            account = new Account(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), new LinkedList<User>());
        }

        // ...and with every line we add one of the joined users
        User user = new User(rs.getInt("u_id"), rs.getString("u_name"));
        if (user.getId() > 0) {
            account.getUsers().add(user);
        }

        return account;
    }
}
```

The DAO interface will then have a method like this:

```
public interface AccountDAO {

    @Mapper(AccountMapper.class)
    @SqlQuery("SELECT Account.id, Account.name, User.id as u_id, User.name as u_name FROM Account LEFT JOIN User ON User.accountId = Account.id WHERE Account.id = :id")
    public List<Account> getAccountById(@Bind("id") int id);

}
```

*Note:* Your abstract DAO class will quietly compile if you use a non-collection return type, e.g. `public Account getAccountById(...);`. However, your mapper will only receive a result set with a single row even if the SQL query would have found multiple rows, which your mapper will happily turn into a single account with a single user. JDBI seems to impose a `LIMIT 1` for `SELECT` queries that have a non-collection return type. It is possible to put concrete methods in your DAO if you declare it as an abstract class, so one option is to wrap up the logic with a public/protected method pair, like so:

```
public abstract class AccountDAO {

    @Mapper(AccountMapper.class)
    @SqlQuery("SELECT Account.id, Account.name, User.id as u_id, User.name as u_name FROM Account LEFT JOIN User ON User.accountId = Account.id WHERE Account.id = :id")
    protected abstract List<Account> _getAccountById(@Bind("id") int id);

    public Account getAccountById(int id) {
        List<Account> accountList = _getAccountById(id);
        if (accountList == null || accountList.size() < 1) {
            // Log it or report error if needed
            return null;
        }
        // The mapper will have given a reference to the same value for every entry in the list
        return accountList.get(accountList.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

This still seems a little cumbersome and low-level to me, as there are usually a lot of joins in working with relational data. I would love to see a better way or having JDBI supporting an abstract operation for this with the SQL object API.

Comment: You can move the first option to the DAO class by simply making it abstract. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26831146/846644

Comment: That's a really nice mapper trick! I added a note and a work around for the list/non-list return type on the DAO method as it caught me off guard.

Comment: It is worth noting here that the second option may not be thread safe at all (due to the parent Account object), unless you know for a fact that JDBI uses a new a instance of this ResultSetMapper each time it executes a query, which I don't really know but still consider a fragile assumption to depend on.

Comment: There is now first-class support for achieving this in JDBI v3. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52586791/1314028

Answer (score 25):

In JDBI v3, you can use [@UseRowReducer](http://jdbi.org/#__userowreducer) to achieve this. The row reducer is called on every row of the joined result which you can "accumulate" into a single object. A simple implementation in your case would look like:

```
public class AccountUserReducer implements LinkedHashMapRowReducer<Integer, Account> {

    @Override
    public void accumulate(final Map<Integer, Account> map, final RowView rowView) {
        final Account account = map.computeIfAbsent(rowView.getColumn("a_id", Integer.class),
            id -> rowView.getRow(Account.class));
        if (rowView.getColumn("u_id", Integer.class) != null) {
            account.addUser(rowView.getRow(User.class));
        }
    }
}
```

You can now apply this reducer on a query that returns the join:

```
@RegisterBeanMapper(value = Account.class, prefix = "a")
@RegisterBeanMapper(value = User.class, prefix = "u")
@SqlQuery("SELECT a.id a_id, a.name a_name, u.id u_id, u.name u_name FROM " +
    "Account a LEFT JOIN User u ON u.accountId = a.id WHERE " +
    "a.id = :id")
@UseRowReducer(AccountUserReducer.class)
Account getAccount(@Bind("id") int id);
```

Note that your `User` and `Account` row/bean mappers can remain unchanged; they simply know how to map an individual row of the user and account tables respectively. Your `Account` class will need a method `addUser()` that is called each time the row reducer is called.

Comment: I'm working on implementing this but I'm only seeing the id fields in my results. If I dig into the actual rowView object, I can easily find all of the fields, but how can I make them all accessible to my addUser function? Right now the only fields that get mapped for both User and Account are the ids.

Comment: Are you sure all the DB column names match up with the property names in your POJOs? If not, `@RegisterBeanMapper` may not work for you; you can also use a regular `@RegisterRowMapper` and implement your own row mappers for your POJOs (which is what I do)

Comment: Ah..so I had a column in my user table, account_id which is a FK value. It wasn't showing a value in addUser() until I added it to the select list as u.account_id u_account_id. I hope this info helps someone else!

Comment: Glad you fixed your issue!

Comment: One caveat with the @UserRowReducer method is that it doesn't allow for streamed processing of ResultSets so if you're processing a very large number of records this isn't going to work for you.

Comment: This is giving me `Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to int` on the `computeIfAbsent` line

Comment: how does this work with an "insert" ?

Answer (score 4):

I have a small library which will be very useful to maintain one to many & one to one relationship.
It also provide more feature for default mappers.

https://github.com/Manikandan-K/jdbi-folder

Answer (score 1):

There's an old google groups post where Brian McAllistair (One of the JDBI authors) does this by mapping each joined row to an interim object, then folding the rows into the target object.

[See the discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jdbi/4e4EP-gVwEQ). [There's test code here](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/master/src/test/java/org/skife/jdbi/v2/docs/TestFoldToObjectGraph.java).

Personally this seems a little unsatisfying since it means writing an extra DBO object and mapper for the interim structure. Still I think this answer should be included for completeness!